# Is it possible to recreate google calendar in compose (a LazyColumn with dynamically placed/anchored views)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Basically, I'd like to recreate the day calendar screen in compose, but I can't figure out how to place the elements dynamically with them being able to overlap (and overlay the scrollable background with the hours)

The only way I can think of doing this would be through canvas, and that kind of defeats the purpose of using compose.
Is this possible to be done with something like a LazyColumn?
Pic of the screen for clarity:

[image]

Comment: You can use `LazyColumn` with `dynamic` or `anchored views`. I would personally combine `ConstraintLayout` and `LazyColumn`.

Comment: For the usecase I mentioned, how would I go about that?
Would the time grid be a background which I would anchor the cards to? In which case, how would I calculate where the anchor points would be?
Perhaps a single ConstraintLayout child in the LazyColumn which would have the cards and the timeslots as separate composables and then anchor them based on the duration?

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the solution approach :***

1. [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout) is the `parent layout`.
2. Create composable [`Function`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/function/Function) for TextViews column. ( or a `custom composable` to **draw** `grid lines` / `labels` )
3. Create composable function for Events. ( could be [`Card`](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/compose/cards) with events details )
4. [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists) for **displaying** [`Events`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageEvents.Event).
5. Anchor [`Events`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/metrics/Event) to the [`Grid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView). ( `custom modifier` for `Position` )
6. [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintSet) for [`Events`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/metrics/Event) and [`Grid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView).

---

**CalendarCompose.kt**

```
@Composable
fun Day(events: ... ) {
    // Constraint and Modifier

    Grid(
        modifier = ... {

        // Modifier and Parent

        }
    )

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = ... {

        // Grid and Dimension

        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun Time(modifier: ... ) {

    // Column, Text and Spacer

}

@Composable
fun Event(modifier: ... ) {

    // Card and Text

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899331/how-can-i-know-the-postion-of-my-layout-in-custom-layout-jetpack-compose can someone help me plz, it is the same concept using custom layouts