# how can i know the postion of my layout in custom layout jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am doing a scrollable week calendar in jetpack compose android, it scrolls past 7 days. When I am scrolling through the layout, how can I know my current postion to show the specific date . Cause layoutinfo is not working with me.
Also how can I disbale clicking on time slots where I have an event.

```
@Composable
fun Schedule(
    bookings: List<Booking>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bookingContent: @Composable (booking: Booking) -> Unit = { BookingCard(booking = it) },
    onEmptyViewClicked: (Int, Int, Int) -> Unit
) {
    val hourHeight = 64.dp

    Layout(
        content = {
            bookings.sortedBy { it.start.localDateTime }
                .forEach { booking ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.bookingData(booking)) {
                        bookingContent(booking)
                    }
                }
        },
        modifier = modifier
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures {
                    val x = it.x.toDp()
                    val y = it.y.toDp()
                    val time = y.value.toInt() / hourHeight.value
                    val selectedDate = time.toInt()
                    println("X: $x, Y: $y")
                    println("selected date $selectedDate")
                    println("Time: $time")
                    val days = selectedDate / 24
                    val startHour = selectedDate - (24 * days)

                    onEmptyViewClicked(days, startHour, selectedDate)

                }
            }
            .drawBehind {
                repeat(167) {
                    drawLine(
                        color = Color.LightGray,
                        start = Offset(0f, (it + 1) * hourHeight.toPx()),
                        end = Offset(size.width, (it + 1) * hourHeight.toPx()),
                        strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx()
                    )
                }
            },
    ) { measureables, constraints ->
        val height = hourHeight.roundToPx() * 168
        val placeablesWithBookings = measureables.map { measurable ->
            val booking = measurable.parentData as Booking
            val bookingDurationMinutes =
                ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(booking.start.localDateTime, booking.end.localDateTime)
            val eventHeight = ((bookingDurationMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()).roundToInt()
            val placeable = measurable.measure(
                constraints.copy(
                    minHeight = eventHeight,
                    maxHeight = eventHeight
                )
            )
            Pair(placeable, booking)
        }
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, height) {
            placeablesWithBookings.forEach { (placeable, booking) ->
                val dayOffset = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
                    LocalDate.now(),
                    booking.start.localDateTime.toLocalDate()
                )
                val bookingOffsetMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
                    LocalTime.MIN,
                    booking.start.localDateTime.toLocalTime()
                )
                val bookingY =
                    (((bookingOffsetMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()) + (dayOffset * hourHeight.roundToPx() * 24)).roundToInt()
                placeable.place(0, bookingY)

            }
        }
    }
}

private class BookingDataModifier(
    val booking: Booking,
) : ParentDataModifier {
    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?) = booking
}

private fun Modifier.bookingData(booking: Booking) = this.then(BookingDataModifier(booking))
```

Here is my booking card view

```
@Composable
fun BookingCard(
    booking: Booking,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(end = 2.dp, bottom = 2.dp)
            .background(
                color = booking.color ?: Color.Green,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
            )
            .padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "${
                booking.start.localDateTime.toLocalTime()
            } - ${booking.end.localDateTime.toLocalTime()}",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
            color = Color.White
        )

        Text(
            text = booking.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
            color = Color.White
        )

        if (booking.description != null) {
            Text(
                text = booking.description,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                color = Color.White
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The BookingTime class for to avoid recomposition :

```
@Stable
data class BookingTime(val localDateTime: LocalDateTime)
```

The bookingsList:

```
val bookings = listOf<Booking>(
    Booking(
        id = 1,
        name = "Dr Gilbert",
        start = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1)),
        end = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2))
    ),
    Booking(
        id = 2,
        name = "Dr Michel",
        start = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1)),
        end = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).plusHours(2))
    ),
    Booking(
        id = 3,
        name = "Dr Nancy",
        start = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2)),
        end = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(2).plusHours(2))
    ),
    Booking(
        id = 4,
        name = "Dr Brian",
        start = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(3)),
        end = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(3).plusHours(2))
    ),
    Booking(
        id = 5,
        name = "Dr Antoine",
        start = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(3)),
        end = BookingTime(LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(5))
    )
)
```

Booking class:

```
data class Booking(
    val id: Id,
    val name: String,
    val start: BookingTime,
    val end: BookingTime,
    val description: String? = null,
    val color: Color? = null
)
```

ScheduleHeaderView:

```
@Composable
fun ScheduleHeader(
    minDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now(),
    maxDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(6),
    dayWidth: Dp = 60.dp,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dayHeader: @Composable (day: LocalDate) -> Unit = { DayLabel(day = it) }
) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        val numDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(minDate, maxDate).toInt() + 1
        items(numDays) { i ->
            // Box(modifier = Modifier.width(dayWidth)) {
            dayHeader(minDate.plusDays(i.toLong()))
            //  }
        }
    }
}
```

I use this class to show the screen:

```
@Composable
 ScheduleView(){
 val verticalScrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
 ScheduleHeader()
   Schedule(
                bookings = bookings,
                modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(verticalScrollState)
                ,
                onEmptyViewClicked = { 
              }
            )
}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `LazyColumn` instead? If can use it with:

`val listState = rememberLazyListState()` and then `istState.firstVisibleItemIndex`

Comment: And for problem number two: create a new composable that takes in a Booking, and also a callback for item clicked `onItemClicked: () -> Unit`. Then, on whatever click callback you are using inside the new composable layout: `if (booking != null) { onItemClicked() } else { // clicked but do nothing since booking is null }`...